# Differentiate this quotient and find the slope? Am I making an error?

Tags: calculus

I have this equation that I want to differentiate:

$$y = \frac{2x}{x^2+1}$$

and so I think $y' =$ (using quotient rule)

$$= \frac{(x^2+1)*2 - 2x(2x)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{2x^2 + 2 - 4x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{-2x^2 + 2}{(x^2 + 1)^2}$$

$$= \frac{-2(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Is that right? Am I making a mistake? I want to find the slope at x = 1 and so given my differential, the slope is = 0 right?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Looks ok to me......+1

Comment: Looks good. Just remember this for quotient rule: low d high minus high d low, square the bottom and here we go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect! I have checked your work and it is flawless. You have explained every step in detail and made it completely clear.